# Database+Tooltip like wowhead

Tags: php, ajax, tooltip

I´m searching a solution for this:

1. I want to have a series of pages where the information is provided on a single page like you see it here: http://www.wowhead.com/quest=12141
2. I want to have the information, which is on the page I've made, in a tooltip. Wowhead does it like this: http://www.wowhead.com/tooltips

**I've tried the following:**

1. I've made a MySQL database with my information in it and I'm able to print them out on the site.
2. Here is my problem. How do I get the informations inside of a tooltip. I can print them out with "php echo", but this would be a bit too complicated for general users to click on and wait for a page load to see them.

**Summary:** I need an easy solution to print out the information on a web site inside of a tooltip.

I hope you have any tips for me...

Comment: If you don't want PHP to 'echo out' whats in the database then I don't see how you hope to accomplish this.

Comment: So how can i get the informatiosn from the site in a tooltip, without a php solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can print all the content at once and show the tooltips using js without ajax requests.
2. I might misunderstood you and if yes - you should take some ajax tutorial